# Mechanism for the conversion of 4-bromobenzyl bromide to 4-bromobenzoic acid using Oxone (potassium peroxymonosulfate)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Oxone is a mild, inexpensive and easy to handle and environmentally benign oxidation agent that has many application in organic synthesis.

[image]

4-Bromobenzyl bromide can be converted to 4-bromobenzoic acid using Oxone. I am curious what would be the mechanism for the oxidation.

The proposed mechanism seems like that, but how the carbocation is formed in the first step?[image]

Comment: This is the simple $\mathrm{S_N1}$ mechanism.

Comment: @Jan, how it is SN1 Reaction?

Comment: Please look it up in your textbook.